# Footer doesn't move down when the left side menu is large

Tags: asp-classic, css

I had redone the CSS to allow the footer to stay at the bottom of our [product page](http://www.ads-pipe.com/ca_en/productTemp.asp?page=N-12_Corrugated_HDPE_Pipe) but it seems that if the left-hand side contains more information than the body does, the footer cuts the left off, instead of moving down to allow the left-menu to be completely shown.
I've tried a number of different solutions to this and I think it may have something to do with the page being dynamically generated (ASP Classic) so I don't have the option of specifying a height.
Any insight into what I should either do, or any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is because the left menu is `position: relative;`, but there are other problems that prevent a simple solution to your page.

My advice is to check other [3 column CSS layouts](http://www.google.com/search?q=three%20column%20css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), like [The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm)